# python bz2 compression of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, bz2

```
>>> import bz2
>>> bz2.compress('hi')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda/lib/python3.4/bz2.py", line 498, in compress
return comp.compress(data) + comp.flush()
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I've seen examples using strings as input but it wont work for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compression algorithms compress bytes, [not text](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

```
3>> bz2.compress(b'hi')
b'BZh91AY&SY\x9a\x89\xb4"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00` \x00!\x00\x82\xb1w$S\x85\t\t\xa8\x9bB '
3>> bz2.compress('hi'.encode('utf-8'))
b'BZh91AY&SY\x9a\x89\xb4"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00` \x00!\x00\x82\xb1w$S\x85\t\t\xa8\x9bB '
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why in the examples shown here they use strings then?

https://pymotw.com/2/bz2/

Comment: @RyanHalabi: `str` in Python 2.x is a bytestring.

Comment: why doesnt a ==c in the following:

a = 'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'                              b = a.encode('utf-8')                             c = b'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'      (sorry for poor editing, it won't let me space it out)

Comment: @RyanHalabi: [Because UTF-8 encodes characters above U+007F as multiple bytes.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @RyanHalabi whenever viewing pymotw.com make sure the url starts with pymotw.com/3 so you are reading the version for python 3. So you should use https://pymotw.com/3/bz2/